# Click anywhere to close menu in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I'm doing this to close my topbar menu but it isn't what I need because it only closes when the menu icon is clicked.

It needs to close when I click anywhere on the website. Is there an easy and efficient way to achieve this with react?

**Navbar.js**

```
  const handleToggle = () => {
    setActive(!isActive);
  };

<div className="account" onClick={handleToggle}><img src={davatar} className="avatar" alt="accountmenu" width="40" height="40" /></div>
```

Comment: https://react-hooks.org/docs/useOutsideClick
I recommend have a look to this article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a package called [react-cool-onclickoutside](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cool-onclickoutside). You can use that to solve this issue

OR you can u can create a custom useOutsideHook [refer here](https://usehooks.com/useOnClickOutside/)

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
// Usage
function App() {
  // Create a ref that we add to the element for which we want to detect outside clicks
  const ref = useRef();
  // State for our modal
  const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  // Call hook passing in the ref and a function to call on outside click
  useOnClickOutside(ref, () => setModalOpen(false));
  return (
    <div>
      {isModalOpen ? (
        <div ref={ref}>
          Hey, I'm a modal. Click anywhere outside of me to close.
        </div>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={() => setModalOpen(true)}>Open Modal</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
// Hook
function useOnClickOutside(ref, handler) {
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const listener = (event) => {
        // Do nothing if clicking ref's element or descendent elements
        if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
          return;
        }
        handler(event);
      };
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", listener);
      document.addEventListener("touchstart", listener);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousedown", listener);
        document.removeEventListener("touchstart", listener);
      };
    },
    // Add ref and handler to effect dependencies
    // It's worth noting that because passed in handler is a new ...
    // ... function on every render that will cause this effect ...
    // ... callback/cleanup to run every render. It's not a big deal ...
    // ... but to optimize you can wrap handler in useCallback before ...
    // ... passing it into this hook.
    [ref, handler]
  );
}
```